# 別フォームでのエラーをキャッチしたい。

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vb.net

少し構造が分かりにくいかもしれませんが、現状をお伝えします。

STEP1：Class1 より Form1を呼び出し（Form1の引数はインターフェイスで定義してありclass1のインスタンスを渡します）

STEP2: Form1のShownイベントより、引数で受け取ったインターフェイスのメソッドを新しいスレッドを作成し、スタートさせます。

STEP3: スタートさせたスレッドのエラーを拾いたいのですが、実行したメソッドの内部ではキャッチされるのですが、上位でトライを書いてみてもキャッチすることができません。

**Class1**

```
dim f1 as new form1(me)
f1.showdialog()
```

**Form1**

```
dim IF as InterFace
sub new (byval IF as InterFace)
   me.InterFace = IF
end sub

' FormShownイベント
Dim Thread1 As New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf threadA))
tread1.isBackGround = true
tread1.start()

private sub threadA
   me.IF.method
end sub
```

エラーをキャッチするタイミングとしては、Form1を呼び出すclass1がベストなのですが、そもそもエラーをキャッチすることができません。
どなたかお分かりになる方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

> エラーをキャッチするタイミングとしては、Form1を呼び出すclass1がベストなのですが、そもそもエラーをキャッチすることができません。

「エラーをキャッチ」と書かれていますが、キャッチという表現をされている以上、例外のキャッチを意図しているものと受け取ります。
例外は呼び出し元に向けて投げられます。しかしスレッドは呼び出し関係にありません。事実、`tread1.start()`を実行すると呼び出し元としては次の行に進みます。ですので別スレッドで発生した例外をキャッチすることはできません。

ただし、Visual Studio 2012から導入された[Async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/hh191564(v=vs.110).aspx)を使用すると別スレッドで実行したにもかかわらず発生した例外は呼び出し元に転送されます。
質問にはVisual Studioのバージョン及び別スレッドで行いたい処理について言及されていないため、このAsync機能を利用できるかは判断できませんので紹介にとどめます。
参考： [Async および Await を使用した非同期プログラミング](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ご丁寧な解答ありがとうございます。説明が足りず、申し訳ありません。私が使用しているのはVisualStudio2010ですので、Async機能は使用できないようですね。スレッドをスタートさせる事＝呼び出し関係ではないのですね。大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

sayuriさんの記述されているとおり例外がClass1でキャッチできないのは実行スレッドが異なるからです。このような場合、`Control.BeginInvoke`メソッドでUIスレッド上での処理を開始することができますので、その中で例外を再スローすれば要望の動作になるかと思います。

```
Private Sub threadA()
    Try

        me.IF.method

    Catch ex As Exception ' Catchを追加

        ThrowException(ex)

    End Try
End Sub

' UIスレッド上で例外をスローするメソッド
Private Sub ThrowException(ex As Exception)

    SyncLock Me ' フラグ用のロック

        ' 例外発生時にすでにフォームが閉じていることも考えられるので判定する
        If _closed Then

            Return

        End If

        ' InvokeRequiredがTrueである場合はスレッドが異なるのでBeginInvokeを行う
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then

            Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of Exception)(AddressOf ThrowException), ex)

            Return

        End If

        ' メインスレッド上で例外を再スロー
        Throw New Exception("threadAで例外が発生しました", ex)

    End SyncLock

End Sub

' フォームが閉じられているかのフラグ
Private _closed As Boolean

' フォームが閉じられたらフラグを立てる
Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed

    SyncLock Me

        _closed = True

    End SyncLock

End Sub
```